# How can we save the widget that will be adding on run (on click of user) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

- We are creating a noticeboard app and we are pinning widgets on board(Staggered Grid View).
- I tried initializing the list - pinnedWidgets in initState() of main.dart (Only thing I could think of) and that's not working.
- We want the items added in the list to be saved, even when we close the app.
- We have used Hive (local database) as database.

[image]

**We are unable to save the state of board.**
(state of the board: widget data that user will be adding on run)

```
    List<Widget> pinnedWidgets = []; //tried putting this in initState()
    pinnedWidgets!.add(
                                StaggeredGridTile.count(
                                  crossAxisCellCount: 2,
                                  mainAxisCellCount: 2,
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: (() {
                                      print('tap on video catched');
                                      print(localfile.path.toString());
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: ((context) => Video(
                                              localfile_path:
                                                  localfile.path)),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }),
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Stack(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            child: Text(
                                              'video link; ${videopath.toString()}',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            // child: Image.file(
                                            //     File(videopath.toString())),
                                            decoration:
                                                BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                blurRadius: 3.0,
                                                spreadRadius: 0.5,
                                                offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                              ),
                                            ]),
                                          ),
                                          Image.asset(
                                            'assets/images/pin.png',
                                            width: 13,
                                            height: 13,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
```

Comment: Where you are storing the state? You are just adding the grid to the list !!

Comment: Exactly. It is a bigger app so for implementing another tasks we just created a list for widgets. We want to save the widgets' data. That's the problem, we want solution for. (Like instead of list, if we can use anything else)

Comment: If you want to store you can use any SQLite plugins or Shared Preferences.

Comment: I think there is slight confusion. We don't just want to save the image or string, instead we want to save the widget that is added in gridview 'during runtime' 'by user'. If shared preferences or SQLite can make this work can you please code an example?

Comment: If you explicitly want to store widgets then it is quite difficult to achieve. Instead, you can convert as data class with position, type, and store using any of the above methods which I mentioned earlier and use those values whenever needed.